# How to get user information when they access my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have a simple website in ASP.NET where I have loaded a DLL. I have published the site via IIS and I only want to show on the user side his Machine Name, logged in user and IP. I have tried the following:

**My DLL:**

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
  {
    public class Class1
    {
      public string getInfo()
      {
        IPAddress[] ips;

        ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

        string returns = null;

    returns = Environment.MachineName + Convert.ToChar(9) + Environment.UserName;
        foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
        {
          if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
          returns += Convert.ToChar(9) + ip.ToString();
        }
        return returns;

    }
  }
}
```

**And in the website:**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClassLibrary1.Class1 cl = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
        Label2.Text = cl.getInfo();
    }
}
```

The output is not what I expected. In my machine, when I access the site i get

```
MyMachineName    Classic .NET AppPool    MyIp
```

And when anyone else opens it, they also get those informations, not their machinename, logged in user and IP.

So my question is how to retrieve their info?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pulling the stats from the machine that is serving the website, not the visitor's machine. You should probably take a look at the [`HttpRequest.ServerVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) `NameValueCollection` instead.

Some of those "variables", particularly the ones you are interested in, are derived from the headers in each web request from the client. Keep in mind that you aren't actually talking *to* the client's machine, these are sent *to you* from the client. Consequently, there's no guarantee that they will be accurate (proxy, etc.), if they're even there at all.

That said, the ones you are probably interested in are:

```
var ip =      HttpRequest.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
var user =    HttpRequest.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"]; // Windows auth
var user =    HttpRequest.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];  // Non-Windows auth
var machine = HttpRequest.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"];
```

[Here's the list of variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx) to pick from.

Comment: For REMOTE_USER to work, IIS/ASP.NET has to be configured to demand authentication.

Comment: @EricLaw: Perhaps `LOGON_USER` would be better then?

Comment: Is there a way of doing this by loading the DLL on the user's side?

Comment: @Guga: No, and it's not necessary. If you display the above values in your web page, the user who visits it will see their machine values (most of the time).